# Need assistance for understanding code for drawing a checkerboard

Tags: java

The book uses this code to draw a checkerboard. The only problem I'm having is understanding the sequence of how the individual squares on drawn on the checkerboard. When I do my calculations it only fills the checkerboard with squares in a diagonal direction from top left to bottom right. The book says the code does this loop 64 times for every square but I'm not sure how it does this 64 times.

For example lets say getHeight() = 72

sqSize = 9

moving in the inner most loop 
double x = 0 * 9 ===> 0 
double y = 0 * 9 ===> 0 
GRect (0, 0, 9, 9,);

double x = 1 * 9 ===> 9  
double y = 1 * 9 ===> 9   
GRect (9, 9, 9, 9,);

double x = 2 * 9 ===> 18   
double y = 2 * 9 ===>18    
GRect (18, 18, 9, 9);

etc...

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.graphics.*;

public class Checkerboard extends GraphicsProgram {

public void run(){

double sqSize = (double) getHeight() / N_ROWS;
for ( int i = 0; i < N_ROWS; i++ ){
    for( int j = 0; j < N_COLUMNS; j++) {
           double x = j * sqSize;
           double y = i * sqSize;
           GRect sq = new GRect(x, y, sqSize, sqSize);
           sq.setFilled(( i + J ) % 2 !=0); 

            }
         }
      }
    private static final int N_ROWS = 8; 
    private static final int N_COLUMNS = 8; 
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two loops - the second loop cycles through each value 0-7, and does so a total of 8 times, because that's how many times the first loop runs. It appears in your explaination that you  are incrementing both values at the same time, as if there was only one loop that increments both values each time through.

It may be helpful to print the values of *i* and *j* inside your loop.

```
(i,j)

(0, 1) (0, 2) (0, 3) ...
(1, 1) (1, 2) (1, 3) ...
...
```

Comment: Is this correct? The inner loops completes then the other loops goes up one value and the inner loops runs again with a new x value?

Comment: @JessicaM: yes, the first loop is going to execute everything in the braces 8 times.  Within the braces is another loop, so the second loop is going to be executed 8 times; each time, the j in the second loop will go from 0-7 also.  Bert's answer and suggestion are both good.

Comment: Quick question. How does the inner loop determine which value to change. What is the signal that x is the outer loop while y is the inner loop?

Comment: The for loop that uses the variable `j` is inside the curly braces of the for loop that uses the variable `i`. Those variables are assigned to `x` and `y` by the lines `double y = i * sqSize;` and `double x = j * sqSize;`

Comment: Also, you could move the line `double y = i * sqSize;` outside of the inner loop - `i` is the same value each time so you're doing an unnecessary calculation each time.

Comment: For example the control line for the inner loop value (j = 0; j < N_COLUMNS; j++). The control line in the inner loops deals with j and isn't j dealing with the x coordinate? Am I incorrect in thinking that way?

Comment: Yes, the `x` is assigned to the result of `j * sqSize`

Comment: In the example above, y = 0 while the x cycles though 0-7 for the x coordinate. After the 1st inner loop is completed, y moves up one value. So y = 1 and x cycles though 0-7 again. Then after that y moves up another one 1 value and then x cycles though 0-7 again. Is this correct? The outer loop deals with y and only increases one value after the inner loop which deals with x finishes its looping cycle?